# setTimeout to open a new window in response to a click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've noticed that when doing

```
$(".sitelink_external").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open(redirectUrl,'_blank')
});
```

it opens a new tab  or window, without calling the pop-up blocker of Chrome, Firefox or IE.

However, I want to create a redirect so that the user will be able to regret, making a timer for the link, and if I do like this:

```
$(".sitelink_external").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout("window.open(redirectUrl,'_blank')", timer * 1000);
});
```

It calls the popup blocker, and doesn't open the popup the way I want, any idea how to resolve this?

EDIT: the answers are great, but don't resolve the problem, as it was working before as well in the same manner.

Comment: ah, I suspect you're hitting the policy rule that says that a popup opening in an event handler is OK - that's user triggered, but one from an async timer event isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a really bad performance synchronous timeout function:

```
function synchronousTimeout (timeout, handler) {
   const start = new Date().getTime()
   while ((new Date().getTime() - start) < timeout) {}
   handler()
}
```

And then simply use it with your click handler

```
$(".sitelink_external").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  synchronousTimeout(timer * 1000, () => window.open(redirectUrl,'_blank'));
});
```

EDIT: I just realised that this questions was from YEAAAARS before, wow :D

Answer (score 0):

Change the setTimeout call to do this instead:

```
setTimeout(function() { window.open(redirectUrl,'_blank') }, timer * 1000);
```

You can't pass a variable the way you were doing it (and it is generally better to pass a function rather than a string that will be eval'd)